# try-catch doesn't catch IOException

Tags: java, try-catch, ioexception

In the following code, I get the `Unreachable catch block for IOException`. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body error(underlined) with the `IOException` in `} catch (IOException e){` what am I doing wrong?

```
class driver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Customer forrest = new Customer("Forrest Gump", 1,
        "42 New Street, New York, New York");
    Customer random = new Customer("Random Name", 2,
        "44 New Street, New York, New York");
    Customer customer[] = { null, forrest, random };
    int whichOption = 1;
    int id = 0;
    char action = ' ';
    char accSrc = ' ';
    char accDest = ' ';
    double amount = 0;
    BankAccount src = null;
    do {

      try{
        // process JOptionPane input information
        String input = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Please enter your transaction information: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
        id = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
        action = Character.toUpperCase((s.next().charAt(0)));

        if (action == 'T') {
          amount = s.nextDouble();
          accSrc = s.next().charAt(0);
          accDest = s.next().charAt(0);
        } else if (action == 'G' || action == 'I') {
          accSrc = s.next().charAt(0);
        } else {
          // if D,W
          amount = s.nextDouble();
          accSrc = s.next().charAt(0);
        }

      } catch (IOException e){

      }
      // taking action accordingly (T)ransfer, (D)eposit, (W)ithdraw, (I)nterest
      if (action == 'T') {

        (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).transfer(amount,
            customer[id].getAccount(accDest));
      } else if (action == 'G') {
        System.out.println("The current balance on your " + accSrc
            + " account is "
            + customer[id].getAccount(accSrc).getBalance() + "\n");
      } else if (action == 'D') {
        (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).deposit(amount);
      } else if (action == 'W') {
        (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).withdraw(amount);
      } else if (action == 'I') {
        (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).computeInterest();
      }
      whichOption = JOptionPane
          .showConfirmDialog(null , "Do you want to continue?");

      System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
          + " auto account is " + customer[id].A.balance);
      System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
          + " savings account is " + customer[id].S.balance);
      System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
          + " checkings account is " + customer[id].C.balance);
      System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
          + " loan account is " + customer[id].L.balance + "\n");

    } while (whichOption == 0);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because none of the operations you perform inside `try/catch` throws IOException.

As per Scanner [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

Most of the Scanner class methods throws either `FileNotFoundException` (Which is not applicable in your case because not reading from file) (or) `IllegalArgumentException` (or) `IllegalStateException`

You need to change `IOException` to either of above exceptions (or) remove try/catch.

Comment: @assylias: Agree. Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the IOException and the try catch since none of the statements inside the try catch is throwing this exception

Answer (score 3):

Seems like nothing you are doing in that `try` block is throwing the `IOException`

Answer (score 3):

No method call in that try block throws a `IOException`, that is why the catch is an unreachable code.

You can safely remove both the try and the catch, as that situation will never happen.

Answer (score 3):

Your `catch` block is empty, indicating that you weren't really going to handle the exception, anyway. You probably had some code in there that made you catch it, but now you don't have it anymore. Just remove the entire surrounding `try-catch` and there will be no further problems.

Comment: what did you do to the source code to remove the indention? i'll make sure to do that next time

Answer (score 1):

`try/catch` block is empty and code is not throw `IOException` but it may throw other exceptions.